# Equalizer settings for USB headset?

Tags: equalizer, usb-headset

I would like to use an Equalizer with my USB headset, the Microsoft LiveChat LX-3000.

The problem here is, that Realtek HD Audio Manager provides no support for USB headsets in their software, and the LifeChat software does not have an Equalizer.

Comment: Must know what the OS is?   You probably already know , but in win7 if a device has some adjustment ability. In | Control Pannel | Sounds | the Playback tab | doubble click on the playback device showing in the picture there, and see if there is at least a "Tone" tab for the device.

Answer (score 4):

Been searching for a good couple of months for the solution to this problem, and FINALLY stumbled upon it out of pure luck me thinks...

There is a program called Equalizer APO which is actually designed as plugin for another sound authoring program. Bonus with this standalone software is that it features system wide integration, whether you use the program it was intended for or not.

It doesn't as such feature a graphical user interface and instead operates through a config.txt file found in the installation folder which contains the equalizer settings. Downside? You have to manually add your desired EQ settings in this config file, i.e. each frequency with its desired sensitivity in decibels, with below an example of what my config file looks like:

```
Preamp: 5 dB
Include: example.txt

Room EQ V5,01
Dated: 29.02.2012 20:04:50

Equaliser: Generic
No measurement
Filter  1: ON  PK       Fc    62,0 Hz  Gain  -2,0 dB  Q  4,00
Filter  2: ON  PK       Fc    32,0 Hz  Gain  4,0 dB  Q  1,00
Filter  3: ON  PK Fc    125,0 Hz  Gain -10,0 dB  Q  1,00  
Filter  4: ON  PK Fc    250,0 Hz  Gain -15,0 dB  Q  1,00   
Filter  5: ON  PK Fc    500,0 Hz  Gain -8,0 dB  Q  1,00   
Filter  6: ON  PK Fc    1000,0 Hz  Gain -4,0 dB  Q  1,00  
Filter  7: ON  PK Fc    1500,0 Hz  Gain 2,0 dB  Q  1,00   
Filter  8: ON  PK Fc    2000,0 Hz  Gain 3,0 dB  Q  1,00  
Filter  9: ON  PK Fc    4000,0 Hz  Gain 5,0 dB  Q  1,00
Filter 10: ON  PK Fc    6000,0 Hz  Gain 2,0 dB  Q  1,00
Filter 11: ON  PK Fc    8000,0 Hz  Gain 3,0 dB  Q  1,00   
Filter 12: ON  PK Fc    12000,0 Hz  Gain 6,0 dB  Q  1,00
Filter 13: ON  PK Fc    16000,0 Hz  Gain 10,0 dB  Q  1,00
```

Basically what I did was 'copy' the settings I used for my Realtek onboard soundcard's equalizer when listening to tunes/watching movies through my speakers and entered them here. I can tell you that the sound of my Lifechat is absolutely awesome, treble, bass, mids... You name it. The VERY cool thing about Equalizer APO is that you can add up to 100 filters as seen above and REALLY fine tune your sound if you have the time on your hands, the above example representing a 13 band equalizer, but yes, it's perfectly possible to have a 100 band equalizer if you have copious amounts of time to waste in setting something like that up, which I don't!

Another downside is that your changes to the config.txt file won't be immediately apparent, so the best way to get the settings you desire is to fire up your music and make changes in the config.txt file, saving the file after each change to hear the effect of your settings. It ends up a bit like building an invisible 'house of sound' but is totally worth it because it works SYSTEM WIDE.

This headset actually has AMAZING sound with the right settings. For the life of me I can't understand why the folks at MS couldn't pull their fingers and code a simple EQ app to ship with the set since some of the okes there could probably have programmed it whilst busily chewing away at his lunch sandwich and drinking his coffee! Sad really Microsoft, but even sadder is that it's not even remotely surprising that you didn't bother to make a plan when the problem is so widely moaned about. Tut tut!

Anyway, that's my solution for the story. Hope this helps someone who's also had the same headache for the last 6 months or so.

Peace from South Africa!

Comment: @user99572isfine How does this NOT answer the question?